# What is the name of the song in the Amiga game, Circus Games?

Tags: game-music-identification, amiga, circus-games

A song from an old game came back to haunt me and I'm quite obsessed to find out what it is.

As background, it sounds nice to play with the piano (a hobby I've picked up in my older years). It is played in this clip (I've included the time offset in the URL):

Does anyone know its name?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's "The man on the flying trapeze".